# Slow angle rotation

Tags: java, slick2d

So apparently, even though I've been through calculus 3, my trig is horribly failing me (I probably can't even call this trig, it's just basic math). 
So basically I have a bunch of images that rotate and I don't want it to be instant. 
I understand how to make it rotate slow but I'm not sure how to calculate which way it should turn.

So if the `target` angle that I want to turn to is under 179 degrees, turn one way. 
If it is over 180 degrees, turn the other way. Not sure if I worded that right but I basically just want it to rotate using the shortest distance. 
Think of a homing missile I suppose.

I have two ways of finding angles, one way is using vectors as shown here:

```
hero = new Vector2f(this.x, this.y);
target = new Vector2f(mouseX, mouseY);
target.sub(hero);

// Calculates the rotation
finalRotation = (int) target.getTheta();
```

The other way is using `atan2` (which looks simpler and I realize I can shorten it to one return statement):

```
direction = Math.atan2(player.x - this.x, player.y - this.y);
return (int) Math.toDegrees(direction);
```

I assume that the method for finding the shortest rotation would work for both. I've been trying a few trial and error things for a while and I'm just stumped.
Help my worthless programming skills! Any help appreciated!

**EDIT:**
What I actually forgot to mention is that I am pointing towards the mouse. 
So if my mouse is at angle 200 from my *'image'* (which is the player) and the player is currently facing 19, 
how would I determine if it should go positive to 200 or down to 0, transfer to 360 and continue down to 200.

**DOUBLE EDIT:**
So I have a working version of what I wanted, but for some reason the final and current rotation are off by 180 and it causes my character to never stop twitching. 
I'll have to work more on it tomorrow. I have to subtract 90 from the `currentRotation` at the end due to the way my sprites are originally rotated.

**TRIPLE EDIT:**
Okay so I had my increment and decrement statements reversed therefore it was trying to go past 180 and then reverse direction. I have perfected it!

```
mouseX = input.getMouseX();
mouseY = input.getMouseY();

hero = new Vector2f(this.x, this.y);
target = new Vector2f(mouseX, mouseY);
target.sub(hero);

// Calculates the rotation
finalRotation = (int) target.getTheta();

if(!(currentRotation <= finalRotation + 1 && currentRotation >= finalRotation - 1)) {
    double tempVal;

    if (currentRotation < finalRotation) {
        tempVal = finalRotation - currentRotation;

        if (tempVal > 180) {
            currentRotation -= .3 * delta;
        } else {
            currentRotation += .3 * delta;
        }
    } else if (currentRotation > finalRotation) {
        tempVal = currentRotation - finalRotation;

        if (tempVal < 180) {
            currentRotation -= .3 * delta;
        } else {
            currentRotation += .3 * delta;
        }               
    }
}

if (currentRotation < 0)
    currentRotation = 359;

if (currentRotation > 360)
    currentRotation = 1;

this.setAngle((int) (currentRotation+90));
```

The input stuff and vectors are from Slick2D.

Comment: Do you just need the smallest angle (see answer by @Amadan), or do you need to know the rotation sense (clockwise or counterclockwise) that produces the smallest angle?

Comment: I need the clockwise or counterclockwise rotation that would produce the smallest angle. As in, if I want to go from 0 to 60, I move positive (0 up to 60) and not negative (360 down to 60).

Answer (score 3):

```
if (finalRotation >= 180) finalRotation = 360 - finalRotation;
```

This will reverse direction for any angle of 180 or above.

Comment: Oh no... it can't be that simple. That is going to make me cry!

Comment: @Paha: lol... It would probably even work with `finalRotation = -finalRotation`, but the `360 - finalRotation` keeps it nicely within 0-360.

Comment: Ahh nice! thanks for the simple answer I couldn't figure out :(

Comment: Actually I'm not sure this method is what I am looking for. What I forgot to explicitly say in my post is that I am getting a direction towards the mouse. So if the mouse is at angle 200 from the image (which is the player I am rotating) and the image is at 19, how would I determine to go down to 0, start at 360 and continue down to 200?